# Allow some characters in flutter field input Regex

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I want to make my form field input to pass through a validator to allow only alphabets number and three symbols - ' / to pass.

```
r'^[A-Za-z0-9\s-/]+$';
```

I have done for all except for symbol ' . Once I add in ' symbols it will assume I close the statement on there. How can I put in the symbols ' .

Comment: Escaping `'` like `\'` should work.

Comment: Sadly is not working \ ' the line will detect it as close parentheses

Comment: Use the same as @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi said. But start and close string expression with r""

Comment: Can you try enclosing whole regex in doublequotes instead of singlequote and then put singlequote inside?

Comment: I change the line to r"^[A-Za-z0-9\s\'-/]+$"  and the regex works for still only - /, the ' symbol still get eliminated

Comment: Now since regex is enclosed in doublequotes, you should not need to escape `'` as `\'`. Can you try unescaping it?

Comment: Still the same problem occured

Comment: Maybe is there other ways can achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, always place `-` at the end of the character class, it is the safest method to use it inside brackets.

Next, adding `'` to a single-quoted string literal is done with an escape single quote, `\'`. Since this does not work, I suspect the problem is that you have curly quotes.

Also, consider using triple-quoted string literals, `r"""<pattern>"""`. This is the most convenient way of writing patterns with quotes.

So you can consider using

```py
pattern = r'''^[A-Za-z0-9\s/'‘’-]+$'''
```

If there is some warning you get, escape these special chars

```py
pattern = r'''^[A-Za-z0-9\s\/\'\‘\’\-]+$'''
```

Comment: by escaping this three types of single quotes it works in my side. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If that singlequote is still bothering you and nothing else worked, then there is another way to achieve it. A little tedious way but works pretty well.

Try using below regex,

```
^[^\u0000-\u001f\u0021-\u0026\u0028-\u002c.\u003a-\u0040\u005b-\u0060\u007b-\uffff]+$
```

Basically this regex excludes the character ranges that are not valid in your character set. I can add detailed explanation once you confirm it works for you and it should as it doesn't have any singlequote in the regex which was causing problem.

Had to use Unicode notation to prohibit matching Unicode characters.

[Check this demo for valid and invalid matches](https://regex101.com/r/pQWWDB/1)

Comment: I have tried this regex. Really appreciate your ans but sadly it not working. However it gives my idea that Unicode characters, which I found the three different types of single quotes (back ,front ,straight) in it. I then able to solve the problem. `r"^[A-Za-z0-9\s/\'\‘\’-]+$"`